# Rails3 – Used lvh.me in development, what to do in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

My Rails application uses a subdomain for each customer.

So i have:

customer1.domain.com/
customer2.domain.com/
customer3.domain.com/

Normally, one would have to add an entry for each customer in /etc/host. Yet I used lvh.me as described in http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3 . And in development mode this has worked quite well.

Now I want to to deploy. Is there a way to avoid adding an entry to etc/host per customer?

I am using Nginx and Phusion Passenger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally end up setting up a DNS server in my development machine. I followed these instructions.

http://intridea.com/2010/6/2/using-bind-locally-on-os-x-for-easy-access-to-subdomains?blog=company

Answer (score 2):

`server_name  *.domain.com;` in your nginx configuration file ( not sure about etc/hosts, isn't that for tracking dns?? ) will allow nginx to serve any subdomain for that domain within that specific `server` block. ( if you have access to the nginx config ), its a wildcard, its then down to you're application how it handles the requests. ie:

```
server {
    server_name *.domain.com;
    blah blah woof ....
}
```

a fairly comprehensive overview can be found [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

Comment: Sure, Nginx can route all incomings requests using a wildcard. I have server_name *.davinci.dev davinci.dev;   But the situation is that I have to add to /etc/hosts this: 127.0.0.1 davinci.local so that my computer knows that when I enter this host -> davinci.local I mean my own computer -> 127.0.0.1 . And with this setup I can access the root domain of my website on my development machine. The problem is that the file /etc/hosts doesn't accept wildcards. I cannot say *.davinci.local and so when I enter customer1.davinci.local on my web browser my computer will not recognise that as localhost.

Comment: And adding a entry to localhost for every client it is quite inconvenient, since there could be hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure your routes.rb in addition with subdomain-fu to do all this